# Regular Expressions - Matching IRC-like parameters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

I am looking to create a IRC-like command format:

```
/commandname parameter1 "parameter 2" "parameter \"3\"" parameter"4 parameter\"5
```

Which would (ideally) give me a list of parameters:

```
parameter1
parameter 2
parameter "3"
parameter"4
parameter\"5
```

Now from what I have read, this isn't at all trivial and might as well be done in some other method.

Thoughts?

Below is C# code that does the job I need:

```
public List<string> ParseIrcCommand(string command)
    {
        command = command.Trim();
        command = command.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' });
        command += ' ';

        List<string> Tokens = new List<string>();

        int tokenStart = 0;
        bool inQuotes = false;
        bool inToken = true;
        string currentToken = "";
        for (int i = tokenStart; i < command.Length; i++)
        {
            char currentChar = command[i];
            char nextChar = (i + 1 >= command.Length ? ' ' : command[i + 1]);

            if (!inQuotes && inToken && currentChar == ' ')
            {
                Tokens.Add(currentToken);
                currentToken = "";
                inToken = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (inQuotes && inToken && currentChar == '"')
            {
                Tokens.Add(currentToken);
                currentToken = "";
                inQuotes = false;
                inToken = false;
                if (nextChar == ' ') i++;
                continue;
            }

            if (inQuotes && inToken && currentChar == '\\' && nextChar == '"')
            {
                i++;
                currentToken += nextChar;
                continue;
            }

            if (!inToken && currentChar != ' ')
            {
                inToken = true;
                tokenStart = i;
                if (currentChar == '"')
                {
                    tokenStart++;
                    inQuotes = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            currentToken += currentChar;
        }

        return Tokens;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly great with regex, but what I have so far is barely functional: `^/\w+( ([^ ]+))*`

Comment: @Bergi I've looked at other StackOverflow questions about using quotes to ignore separators and they talk about back references and some other stuff that makes my head hurt :P

Comment: @Ruirize: Do you know how to parse the command if you are to write a normal program rather than a regex? (You don't need to write one, but you should know very detailed about how to do so) If you know how to, then probably a regex solution is possible. You need to define the grammar for the command - it will help greatly in writing a regex.

Comment: I will see if I can get a C# version working (non regex). I will comment & update the question when done.

Comment: I have added the C# method as requested @nhahtdh

Comment: @Ruirize: So you parse the command the same way as the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown your code - that's good, but it seems that you haven't thought about whether it is reasonable to parse the command like that:

- Firstly, your code will allow new line character inside the command name and parameters. It would be reasonable if you assume that new line character can never be there.
- Secondly, `\` also needs to be escaped like `"`, since there will be no way to specify a single `\` at the end of a parameter without causing any confusion.
- Thirdly, it is a bit weird to have the command name parsed the same way as parameters - command names are usually per-determined and fixed, so there is no need to allow for flexible ways to specify it.

I cannot think of one-line solution in JavaScript that is *general*. JavaScript regex lacks `\G`, which asserts the last match boundary. So my solution will have to make do with beginning of string assertion `^` and chomping off the string as a token is matched.

(There is not much code here, mostly comments)

```
function parseCommand(str) {
    /*
     * Trim() in C# will trim off all whitespace characters
     * \s in JavaScript regex also match any whitespace character
     * However, the set of characters considered as whitespace might not be
     * equivalent
     * But you can be sure that \r, \n, \t, space (ASCII 32) are included.
     * 
     * However, allowing all those whitespace characters in the command
     * is questionable.
     */
    str = str.replace(/^\s*\//, "");

    /* Look-ahead (?!") is needed to prevent matching of quoted parameter with
     * missing closing quote
     * The look-ahead comes from the fact that your code does not backtrack
     * while the regex engine will backtrack. Possessive qualifier can prevent
     * backtracking, but it is not supported by JavaScript RegExp.
     *
     * We emulate the effect of \G by using ^ and repeatedly chomping off
     * the string.
     *
     * The regex will match 2 cases:
     * (?!")([^ ]+)
     * This will match non-quoted tokens, which are not allowed to 
     * contain spaces
     * The token is captured into capturing group 1
     *
     * "((?:[^\\"]|\\[\\"])*)"
     * This will match quoted tokens, which consists of 0 or more:
     * non-quote-or-backslash [^\\"] OR escaped quote \"
     * OR escaped backslash \\
     * The text inside the quote is captured into capturing group 2
     */
    var regex = /^ *(?:(?!")([^ ]+)|"((?:[^\\"]|\\[\\"])*)")/;
    var tokens = [];
    var arr;

    while ((arr = str.match(regex)) !== null) {
        if (arr[1] !== void 0) {
            // Non-space token
            tokens.push(arr[1]);
        } else {
            // Quoted token, needs extra processing to
            // convert escaped character back
            tokens.push(arr[2].replace(/\\([\\"])/g, '$1'));
        }

        // Remove the matched text
        str = str.substring(arr[0].length);
    }

    // Test that the leftover consists of only space characters
    if (/^ *$/.test(str)) {
        return tokens;
    } else {
        // The only way to reach here is opened quoted token
        // Your code returns the tokens successfully parsed
        // but I think it is better to show an error here.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic - very well explained. Thank you!

Comment: @nhahtdh: I suggest changing `\\[\\"]` to `\\.` to [prevent it from failing in bizarre cases, with other backslashes](https://regex101.com/r/jR8qY9/1)

Comment: @Mariano: Do note that I write this regex based on the code in the question. If the language design decides to reject ``\`` followed by arbitrary character, then so be it - it's a valid decision.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Fair enough. I know IRC allows it, but it's not stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple regex that matches the command line you wrote.

```
/\w+\s((("([^\\"]*\\")*[^\\"]*")|[^ ]+)(\b|\s+))+$
```

- `/\w+\s` finds the first part of your command
- `(((`
- `"([^\\"]*\\")*` finds any string starting with `"` that doesn't contain `\"` followed by a `\"` one or more times (thus allowing `"something\"`, `"some\"thing\"` and so on
- `[^\\"]*"` followed by a list of characters not containing `\` or `"` and at last a `"`
- `)|[^ ]+` this is an alternative: finds any nonspace character sequence
- `)`
- `(\b|\s+)` all followerd by a space or a word boundary
- `)+$` one or more times, one per command, until the end of the string

I'm afraid that this can fail sometimes, but I posted this to show that sometimes the arguments have a structure based on repetition, for example see `"something\"something\"something\"end"` where the repeated structure is `something\"`, and you can use this idea to build your regex

Comment: This will only get the last group as part of the match: `'/commandname parameter1 "parameter 2" "parameter \"3\"" parameter"4 parameter\"5'.match(/\/\w+\s((("([^\\"]*\\")*[^\\"]*")|[^ ]+)(\b|\s+))+$/)`

Comment: You are right, this was just an example. To get the single tokens I think the correct regex could be `((("([^\\"]*\\")*[^\\"]*")|[^ ]+)(\b|\s+))` repeated through the whole string, of course after getting the command string with `/\w+`. Edited btw, thanks