# How do I parse command line arguments like Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() does?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm reading a shortcut using the COM "Windows Script Host Object Model" IWshRuntimeLibrary like this:

```
IWshShell wsh = new WshShellClass();
IWshShortcut sc = (IWshShortcut)wsh.CreateShortcut(shortcutFile);
string arguments = sc.Arguments;
```

This gives me the arguments from the shortcut, say it looks like:

```
-a "c:\temp\a 1.txt" -b "b.exe -c \"c:\temp\c -2.txt\" -d d.txt" -e test
```

Which is not as a contrived example as you may think... How can I do the same as GetCommandLineArgs and get:

```
args {string[6]}
[0] = "-a"
[1] = "c:\\temp\\a 1.txt"
[2] = "-b"
[3] = "b.exe -c \"c:\\temp\\c -2.txt\" -d d.txt"
[4] = "-e"
[5] = "test"
```

I'm thinking Regex, but this is beyond my bracketing.

[edit] I'd prefer a regex, but I'll look at the code and classes mentioned.

The rules seem to be:

- Split on spaces,
- unless the space is within double quotes (").
- Strings within double quotes may contain double quotes escaped with a backslash (\").
- Other backslashes may appear on their own but should be treated as a normal character

The arguments and array in the previous two code sections would be an appropriate test.

[edit]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/749653/350188 has answered my question. It calls the native system function and gives me exactly the same results as GetCommandLineArgs() with:

```
string[] splitArguments = CommandLineToArgs(arguments);
```

Comment: Do you understand how the command line parser works? (I can write a regex to parse if I know how it parses the string).

Comment: On first sight, I think that you won't get around regex... Our you split it on whitespaces and put it together again...

Comment: There's a long-time class available for handling this, let me look. For starts, [here's one](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) and [another](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3852/Automatic-Command-Line-Parsing-in-C).

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727065/regular-expressions-matching-irc-like-parameters/14735486#14735486) (you can test right away in the browser). If you think it fits what you need, then I will post it as an answer (with modified regex, since regex in .NET is more powerful).

Comment: may be this library can help http://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: A regex would be ideal, @nhahtdh if it could do the above that would be enough for my problem.

Comment: @webturner: I can write a regex, but unless I know the specific format, the regex may not work as expected. If you yourself don't know the specific format, then I suggest that you use an existing solution.

Comment: I can thing of a really bad, but reliable way; launching a process, and then remoting back the args ;p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string containing command-line parameters into string\[\] in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298830/split-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @hvd Yes, I've tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/749653/350188 and it seems the best. I've voted to close as a dupe of that Q.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really tricky about this. You can use basic C# syntax to examine the individual characters are parse out what you need.

For example, you can `String.IndexOf()` to locate specific characters you are looking for. And you can use `String.Substring()` to extract a portion of a string.

I've posted the code I did to parse a command line in the article [A C# Command-Line Parser](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-c-command-line-parser).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer

Comment: @nhahtdh but Jonathan wrote that article himself. If the link would get rotten, wouldn't he also be the one to replace it? Also, there is a lot of code in the linked example. Should he post all of it here?

Comment: This does not appear to parse strings the way asked in the question.

Comment: @Default: This should probably be raised on meta. (I only point out that this post might get flagged and deleted in this state. I don't know a better alternative, so I didn't downvote or flag).

Comment: @hvd: Right, it doesn't seem to support escaped quote `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and robust solution will be to use some implementation of parser, for example, [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3111/C-NET-Command-Line-Arguments-Parser) or library like [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) depends on what exactly do you need in your application.

Answer (score -3):

If you simply want the arguments in an array like GetCommandLineArgs produces, you can use string.Split:

```
string[] args = arguments.Split(' ');
```

Comment: does this account for `"`?

Comment: No it doesn't account for " or the \"