# Splitting a string into parts, including quoted strings

Tags: regex, string, haxe

So suppose I have this line:

```
print "Hello world!" out.txt
```

And I want to split it into:

```
print
"Hello world!"
out.txt
```

What would be the regular expression to match these?

Note that there must be a space between each of them. For example, if I had this:

```
print"Hello world!"out.txt
```

I would get:

```
print"Hello
world!"out.txt
```

The language I'm using is Haxe.

Comment: What are "these" ? the two first examples are contradictory. In the first one you replace each space by a line feed, except the one in the string, while in the second one, you split anytime there is a space, no matter if it is in a string or not. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Regexes usually work differently across languages.

Comment: Where is the grammar of the tokens? Haxe seems to be a language that can be compiled into other languages. What is your target language? It's foolhardy to write a regex without knowing what else you want to support with your command line-like format.

Comment: @Francis: The first block is the line I want to parse, the second block is the bits of the string that the regex should match, each on a different line. So the regex should grab `print`, `"Hello world!"` and `out.txt` from the first block. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @melpomene: Whoops, looks like you're right; the two current answers both don't compile. I thought the syntax was usually the same between languages, since I've used non-Haxe examples before.

Comment: @nhahtdh: My target is Neko; to my knowledge Haxe compiles directly to bytecode for that. In any case this is purely supposed to separate lines into chunks (like arguments) that I will later on use separately.

Comment: @puggsoy: "Should grab something from some simple input" and a grammar is different. Let's say - how can `"` be specified in between quotes? Do you allow the last string to be an unclosed quoted string e.g. `"not closed`? You might want to take a look at a similar (not the same) question for an idea of what I'm talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727065/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Mark Knol's answer, this should work as expected for all your test strings so far:

```
static function main() {
    var command = 'print "Hello to you world!" out.txt';

    var regexp:EReg = ~/("[^"]+"|[^\s]+)/g;

    var result = [];
    var pos = 0;

    while (regexp.matchSub(command, pos)) {
        result.push(regexp.matched(0));
        var match = regexp.matchedPos();
        pos = match.pos + match.len;
    }

    trace(result);
}
```

Demo: http://try.haxe.org/#5c0B1

EDIT:
As pointed out in comments, if your use case is to split different parts of a command line, then it should be better to have a parser handle it, and not a regex.

These libs might help:

- https://github.com/Simn/hxargs
- https://github.com/Ohmnivore/HxCLAP

Comment: This seems to work best, thanks! However you're probably right, I've been thinking manually parsing it is probably better. Those libraries don't seem to do exactly what I want; I'm not parsing command-line arguments exactly, rather a custom scripting syntax. I can implement my own one for that though, I just initially thought that a regex might be more efficient. All the same, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions in Haxe using the EReg api class:

**Demo:**
http://try.haxe.org/#76Ea0

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var command = 'print "Hello world!" out.txt';
        var regexp:EReg = ~/\s(?![\w!.]+")/g;
        var result = regexp.replace(command, "\n");
        js.Browser.alert(result);
    }
}
```

About Haxe regular expressions:
http://haxe.org/manual/std-regex.html

About regular expressions replacement:
http://haxe.org/manual/std-regex-replace.html

EReg class API documentation:
http://api.haxe.org/EReg.html

Comment: Despite this not being exactly what I asked for (matching the words), I can use EReg.split() to split it into each word, which is pretty much what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately this only works if the string within the quotes has a single space. For example if I replace `"Hello world!"` with `"Hello to you world!"` it gets split into `"Hello`, `to`, and `you world!"`.

Answer (score 0):

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT3cU6/2)

```
\s(?![\w!.]+"\s)
```

an example worked for these two case,maybe someone have more better solution